# How to use jQuery selector/find() against text string without inserting into the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, documentfragment

I have a text string i'm trying to select the spans from using jQuery.  I'd like to grab the spans w/o adding the element to the dom -- if that's possible?

After reading the jquery docs i was under the assumption that i could create a fragment by wrapping the string in a jquery selector tag, then using.find() to find the elements i want.

I have code that is similar to this but from the looks of the last line, it's obvious that no spans are being selected; any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
// 'text' is normally generated automatically... 
// just made it an escaped string for example purposes.
var text ="<span id=\"blah1\">Y</span><br/><span id=\"blah2\">o</span><br/>";
var spans = $(text).find('span');
console.log(text); // => <span id="blah1">Y</span><br/><span id="blah2">o</span><br/>
console.log(spans.length); // => 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you manipulating HTML as text? That's simply absurd. in-line HTML is the devil.

Comment: Maybe it's an HTML string that is being returned from an AJAX call, or being created and returned from a template. ( I hope )

Comment: @bstakes ajax should never return HTML as a string. And templates should not return HTML they should return Nodes.

Comment: The HTML is actually the result of a user selecting text on the page and I'm trying to select the elements that I "care" about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), not [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
var text ="<span id=\"blah1\">Y</span><br/><span id=\"blah2\">o</span><br/>";
var spans = $(text).filter('span');
console.log(spans.length);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PNFVP/)

From the jQuery docs

filter:

> The supplied selector is tested against each element; all elements
>   matching the selector will be included in the result.

find:

> the .find() method allows us to search through the descendants of
>   these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from
>   the matching elements.

with your html fragment, there is no wrapper element, so there is no descendants, hence why find() does not work.

You are basically doing:

```
var elems = jQuery("<span id=\"blah1\">Y</span>").add("<br/>").add("<span id=\"blah2\">o</span>").add("<br/>");
```

If you want find to work with `find()`, you need to wrap it in an element.

```
var text ="<span id=\"blah1\">Y</span><br/><span id=\"blah2\">o</span><br/>"; 
var spans = jQuery("<div></div>").append(text).find("span");
console.log(spans.length);
```

Comment: Because `.find` looks in the children of the nodes, where as `filter` filters the current set

Comment: just curious... can you explain why find doesn't work? Does it only work on elements actually in the DOM and not jquery objects?

Comment: Edited it with explanation and how to do it with `find()`

Comment: @epascarello thank you -- i have benchmarked the differences between the two methods -- filter comes out faster. http://pastie.org/2823600

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in this case:

```
var text ="<span id=\"blah1\">Y</span><br/><span id=\"blah2\">o</span><br/>";
var spans = $(text).filter('span');
console.log(spans.length); // 2
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TGY3J/

Or wrap it in a `<div>` and use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var text ="<span id=\"blah1\">Y</span><br/><span id=\"blah2\">o</span><br/>";
var spans = $('<div>' + text + '</div>').find('span');
console.log(spans.length); // 2
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qbCjk/

`find` works on descendants but without the `<div>` wrapper, your `$(text)` doesn't have any `<span>` descendants. Wrapping your HTML in a `<div>` is probably your best bet, that way you don't have to worry about how deep your desired elements are.